# iPhone - detect nearby bluetooth devices

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Is it possible to find bluetooth-enabled devices near my iphone from an app? I am able to do it using the GameKit framework, but that has a limitation that both devices must have my app installed and running.

Is there a way to detect iPhone devices nearby using bluetooth even if they are not running the same app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. Apple doesn't give the iPhone much Bluetooth interactivity, except for the wireless headphones and what you can do with GK.

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to confirm if what I found till now was true :)